# DDD: (Domain And ViewModel)=> common Behaviors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm new to `DDD` and I don't know what to do with common behaviors of domain which should be done in `ViewModel` .

say I have an `Order.Ship()` which should be called during data entry. It seems that this operation should be done by my `ViewModel`  (during data entry).

I'm wrapping the `DTO` by a `ViewModel` And each `DTO`  got from an `ApiController` , should I place the `Ship()` inside the `Order Entity` or `ViewModel` ?

What is the usage of `Domain Behaviors` here while I'm just moving state to the `ViewModel` ?

Am I in a right road?

Comment: To compute a salary is most likely business logic and should be done in the domain, not in the view.  If you compute it in your ViewModel, you are using a Smart UI, which you'll probably want to avoid.

Comment: @Alexander Langer: just edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm new to DDD and I don't know what to do with common behaviors of domain which should be done in ViewModel .

No, Domain behaviour should stay in the domain and should never leak out to other layers. Especially to the UI.

> say I have an Order.Ship() which should be done while data entry. It seems this operation should be done by my ViewModel (while data entry).

ViewModel is just a DTO and should not have other logic than just formatting the data for the view, validating it, etc. **So no, no domain logic should be invoked inside your ViewModel**. You should have instead a kind of Application services layer (it's not mandatory but often adds cleaner separation of responsibilities) which sits between the UI and the domain layer. This application layer could take Cross cutting concerns responsibilities like Logging, Tranasactions, etc. Generally this application layer is made of business uses cases like "Shipping Order" in which you can then invoke you business logic `Order.Ship()`. If you don't have this application layer, so it's the role of ApiControllers take care of that responsibility.

> I'm wrapping the DTO by a ViewModel And each DTO got from an ApiController , should I place the Ship() inside the Order Entity or ViewModel ?

If the `Ship()` method is a domain logic it should be on the Domain entity or domain service.

> What is the usage of Domain Behaviors here while I'm just moving state to the ViewModel ?

I think that you mean moving the state to ViewModel by **querying** the state of the domain. Even if I don't think it's a good idea to query the domain model which is mostly designed for "commands" and not for queries. However if you do so, it's the responsibility of the ApiController (or application service if you have one) to "transfrom" the state of the domain to the ViewModels (DTO).

Comment: Thanks, Is there any simpler way to minimize calls to `APIController`s in this approach ?(because I can make it without client/server calls)

Comment: What do you mean ? ApiController sits in front of the user/machine boundary (interaction). So if you want to minimize calls you have to use caching which is good way to do implementing Restful services.

Comment: I mean some operations can be done in client side without calling `server side services` (my client app is `WPF`) and affects the state of its `ViewModel` or `DTO` and then passes it to the `server side service` and then `server side service` applies changes to `Entity`.

Comment: And in this situation state of `DTO` changes to 'what the result of calling the server side service` should do for us, and copying the `DTO` to `Entity` is enough for the `Domain` to find out the state changes